# Python Telegram Bot - The bot does not respond to messages

Tags: python, sql, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I Create a telegram bat for pharmacy sharing, in python, which will receive information gradually by requests:

1. Surname, First Name, Patronymic
2. name of medicine
3. expiration date
4. QR code in the form of an image
5. What he wants to get in return. ("reward")
6. Telegram ID for further sending messages by the book about the possibility of obtaining a medicine by geolocation.
   All information is stored in the table, each application has an individual ID.
   The scheme of work: the user make a request that he can provide someone with medicine and what he wants to get in return. The person who indicated this medicine as a "reward" received a message about the geolocation of the medicine and contact details. I use the SQLite3
   **PROBLEM:** I send a message to the bot, and it does not respond to them. Gives only the initial information and that's it.

```
import sqlite3
from typing import Type

import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, updater

from main import conn


def start(update, context):
    message = "Welcome to the Pharmacy Sharing bot! To submit a request, please send the following information one by one:\n\n"
    message += "1. Surname, First Name, Patronymic\n"
    message += "2. Name of medicine\n"
    message += "3. Expiration date (DD.MM.YYYY)\n"
    message += "4. QR code image\n"
    message += "5. What you want to get in return\n"
    message += "6. Your Telegram ID\n\n"
    message += "Once you have sent all of the required information, we will store your request and assign it a unique ID. When someone requests the medicine as a reward, we will send you a message with the geolocation of the medicine and contact details."
    update.message.reply_text(message)

def handle_text(update, context):
    # Check if the user has already submitted a request
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE telegram_id=?", (user_id,))
    row = c.fetchone()
    if not row:
        # User hasn't submitted a request yet, so store the surname, first name, and patronymic
        surname, first_name, patronymic = update.message.text.split()
        c.execute(
            "INSERT INTO requests (surname, first_name, patronymic, telegram_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (surname, first_name, patronymic, user_id))
        conn.commit()
        update.message.reply_text("Thanks, please send the name of the medicine.")
    else:
        if not row[4]:
            # Store the name of the user
            c.execute("UPDATE requests SET user_name=? WHERE id=?", (update.message.text, row[0]))
            conn.commit()
        elif not row[5]:
            # Store the name of the medicine
            c.execute("UPDATE requests SET medicine_name=? WHERE id=?", (update.message.text, row[0]))
            conn.commit()
            # Prompt for the expiration date
            update.message.reply_text("Thanks, please send the expiration date (DD.MM.YYYY).")
        elif not row[6]:
            # Store the expiration date
            c.execute("UPDATE requests SET expiration_date=? WHERE id=?", (update.message.text, row[0]))
            conn.commit()
            # Prompt for the QR code image
            update.message.reply_text("Thanks, please send the QR code image.")
        elif not row[7]:
            # Store the QR code image
            qr_code = update.message.photo[-1].get_file().download_as_bytearray()
            c.execute("UPDATE requests SET qr_code=? WHERE id=?", (qr_code, row[0]))
            conn.commit()
            # Prompt for what the user wants in return
            update.message.reply_text("Thanks, please send what you want to get in return.")
            # Set the flag for what the user wants in return to True
            c.execute("UPDATE requests SET wants_in_return=? WHERE id=?", (True, row[0]))
            conn.commit()
            # Prompt for the Telegram ID
            update.message.reply_text("Thanks, please send your Telegram ID for further communication.")
        elif not row[8]:
            # Store the user's Telegram ID
            c.execute("UPDATE requests SET telegram_id=? WHERE id=?", (update.message.text, row[0]))
            conn.commit()
            update.message.reply_text("Thank you for submitting your request! Your request ID is {}.".format(row[0]))

def handle_photo(update, context):
    # Check if the user has already submitted a request
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id

def handle_photo(update, context):
    # Check if the user has already submitted a request
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE telegram_id=?", (user_id,))
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row and not row[6]:
        # Store the QR code image
        qr_code = update.message.photo[-1].get_file().download_as_bytearray()
        c.execute("UPDATE requests SET qr_code=? WHERE id=?", (qr_code, row[0]))
        conn.commit()
        update.message.reply_text("Thanks, please send what you want to get in return.")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Please submit a request first and then send the QR code image.")

def request_medicine(update, context):
    # Get the ID of the request for the requested medicine
    medicine_name = update.message.text
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE medicine_name=? AND telegram_id!=?",
              (medicine_name, update.message.from_user.id))
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row:
        # Send the geolocation of the medicine and contact details to the user who submitted the request
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=row[8],
                                 text="Someone has requested the medicine {} that you have offered as a reward. Please reply to this message with the geolocation of the medicine and contact details.".format(
                                     medicine_name))
    else:
        update.message.reply_text(
            "Sorry, no one has offered the medicine {} as a reward yet.".format(medicine_name))
# Add the handlers to the dispatcher
        dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
        dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
        dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(telegram.ext.filters.Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_text))
        dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(telegram.ext.filters.Filters.photo & ~Filters.command, handle_photo))
        dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(telegram.ext.filters.Filters.regex(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$'), request_medicine))


        updater.start_polling()


conn.close()
```

I tried to make a check, but nothing happened, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConversationHandler

```
# Define conversation steps
TITLE,DESCRIPTION,MIRROR,CATEGORY,URL_STEP, END  = range(6)

 updater = Updater(config["BOT_TOKEN"],use_context=True)
 dp = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('add', start_dialog, pass_args=True)],
        states={
            TITLE: [MessageHandler(Filters.chat_type.private & Filters.text & ~Filters.command, get_title,pass_user_data=True, pass_chat_data=True)],
            DESCRIPTION: [MessageHandler(Filters.chat_type.private & Filters.text & ~Filters.command, get_description)],
            MIRROR: [MessageHandler(Filters.chat_type.private & Filters.text & ~Filters.command, get_mirror)],
            CATEGORY: [CallbackQueryHandler(category_callback)],
            URL_STEP: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile('^(http|https)://')) & Filters.chat_type.private & ~Filters.command, get_url)],
            END: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & Filters.chat_type.private & ~Filters.command, end_conversation)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel, Filters.chat_type.private), CommandHandler('Y', end_conversation, Filters.chat_type.private)],
        allow_reentry=True,
        per_user=True,
        per_chat=False,
        name="Add app dialog"
    )

dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
```

Function to start dialog

```
def start_dialog(update, context) -> int:
        user_id = update.message.from_user.id
        user = update.message.from_user
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Hello there, lets start add app?")
       return TITLE
```

And then each function returns next step in enumerator like

```
def get_title(update, context)-> int:
    context.user_data['title'] = update.message.text
    user = update.message.from_user
    update.message.reply_text(f"Give me now somekind of description?")
    return DESCRIPTION
```

etc